# interpreting gdb segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb, valgrind

I have googled, froogled, moogled and doogled :-(

raspian

If I run my program under gdb I get:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/pi/axcept/a 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-
gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
axcept v:1.0 20170710
running
[New Thread 0x768e3450 (LWP 6671)]
[Thread 0x768e3450 (LWP 6671) exited]
*** Error in `/home/pi/axcept/a': double free or corruption (out): 
0x00025178 ***

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x76a1af70 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at 
../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or 
directory.
(gdb) where
#0  0x76a1af70 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at 
../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#1  0x76a1c324 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x76a56954 in __libc_message (do_abort=<optimized out>, 
fmt=0x76b0c6e8 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n") at 
../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#3  0x76a5cb80 in malloc_printerr (action=1, str=0x76b0c860 "double 
free or corruption (out)", ptr=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:4996
#4  0x76a5db24 in _int_free (av=<optimized out>, p=<optimized out>, 
have_lock=1992996040) at malloc.c:3840
#5  0x76a7d72c in tzset_internal (always=0, explicit=1991424272) at 
tzset.c:443
#6  0x76a7db5c in __tz_convert (timer=0x7efff1e0, use_localtime=1, 
tp=0x76b2d2cc <_tmbuf>) at tzset.c:632
#7  0x00011190 in get_today () at today.c:17
#8  0x00012f14 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7efff374) at axcept.c:333
(gdb) list
51  in ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c
(gdb)
```

in axcept.c around 333 I have:

```
...
initialise_db();
read_parameters(0);
get_today();
....
```

but both read_parameters and get_today are more or less stolen from official gnu examples.

from my makefile:

```
CC=gcc 
CCFLAGS=  -fgnu89-inline -g -v -da -Q -std=c99 -I/usr/local/include -
L/usr/local/lib -lwiringPi -I/usr/include/mysql/ -I/home/pi/logging/  
`mysql_config --cflags --libs` -lwiringPi -lwiringPiDev -lpthread -lm 
-lcrypt -lrt
```

I have tried valgrind -v --track-origins=yes myprog, but it leaves me no wiser.

Now punch drunk!

Comment: double free or corruption means that you're `free`ing something twice, or that somewhere something overwrote the bookkeeping outside the `malloc`ated object. The problem can manifest itself later. `valgrind` should be the solution...

Comment: Bad choice of code sample. What's going on at today.c:17 seems to be more helpful than axcept.c:333. I always start debugging by the innermost call I have.

Comment: what does `valgrind` show?

Answer (score 3):

Double free or corruption means that you're `free`ing something twice, or that somewhere something overwrote the bookkeeping outside the `malloc`ated object. The problem can manifest itself later - here it is `malloc` that noticed the problem, so the actual heap corruption occurs before.

If valgrind doesn't seem to help (well, it should), try if you can replicate this bug by replacing the `get_today()` call with a useless malloc for example; if it works, then you can try to trace it in the code by moving and removing parts of the code until you will have a MCVE (which probably will resolve by itself).

Comment: Got it!  I was suffering an array out of bounds in read_parameters().  Thanks a lot everyone.